Node.js 'JavaScript heap out of memory' error when building TypeScript app on EC2 instance
I'm encountering a "JavaScript heap out of memory" error while trying to build my Node.js TypeScript application on an EC2 instance. The build process fails with a fatal error related to memory allocation. Below is the error message and stack trace I receive.
Problem:
When I run the build command for my Node.js TypeScript application on an EC2 instance, it crashes with the following error:

Details:
Node.js version: 20.14.0
TypeScript version: 5.4.5
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on EC2
EC2 instance type: t3.medium
Question:
What could be causing the "JavaScript heap out of memory" error during the build process despite increasing the memory limit and upgrading the EC2 instance, and how can I effectively troubleshoot and resolve this issue?
Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!
Attempts:
Here are the steps I've taken to try to resolve the issue:
**

Increased memory limit:** I tried increasing the memory limit by running the build command with the --max-old-space-size flag

I set the NODE_OPTIONS to --max-old-space-size=4096, --max-old-space-size=8192 and tried.

Adjusted EC2 instance type: I ensured that the EC2 instance has sufficient memory by upgrading to a larger instance type.

I tried changing the node version to 14 and 18 from 20.


I'm trying to build my node.js app by compiling the typescript files
using the command: tsc -b
Also by running npm run build which is configured in package.json
